# How to point domain name to EC2 from registrar

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, domain, nameserver, domain-registrar

I have searched for that question, i find several answer but I haven't found appropriate for me.
I have created Elastic IP, and when I enter into control panel of my registrar it asks names servers, but I have found one in Public DNS, but it asks second one.
What to do?

Comment: Who is your registrar ? Do they provide name services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're a little confused as to how DNS/Domain registrations are linked.

Your domain registrar handles your purchase of the domain, and pointing it to a set of *domain name servers*. Presuming your registrar doesn't provide DNS, you shouldn't need to tell them what IP you're hosting the site on.

You will need a DNS provider (which may or may not be the same company as your registrar, most registrars provide some kind of DNS service), who will provide 2 or more name servers on the internet, and who will keep a database of some kind which links the two things up.

For example, your domain registrar might be Acme Inc., which for some reason let's say doesn't provide a DNS service. You'd login to the website for Acme, and set your domain name servers to the DNS servers provided by Bcme, your example DNS provider (e.g ns0.bcme.com and ns1.bcme.com).

You'd need to inform Bcme that your website (domain name) is x.com, and that your IP address is whatever Amazon have given you.

Amazon provide DNS service via "[Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/)" - which is $1pcm/domain, but other DNS providers are available.